# What is it called when something sounds correct but actually is not always true, or even bad?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, phrase-requests

Sometimes the way you express things can influence or persuade the way people think. You can tell someone a false fact but say it with confidence and they will believe you. Sometimes things that sound like inspirational quotes are actually not very valid philosophies and can actually be toxic. People seem to be constructing philosophies on life about how things should be when they don't really have any foundation to them other than sounding like the moral thing to do or sounding more correct. So what is this called? I hope what I am saying makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

Pathos comes to mind, where rhetoric is designed to persuade or influence through the speaker's appeal to emotion.  According to OED, Pathos is defined as:

> (in writing, speech and plays) the power of a performance, description, etc. to make you feel sympathy or be sad.

This is the case whether the rhetoric is true or not.